# Accessing VirtualBox with libvirt from a guest

Tags: mac-osx, virtualbox, libvirt

I have installed libvirt on OSX, and from outside a virtualbox I can access it using virsh no problem. However, I want to access it from inside a guest, and this is giving me the hopelessly useless error:

```
[root@foreman01 ~]# virsh -c vbox://192.168.56.1/session
setlocale: No such file or directory
error: Cannot read CA certificate '/etc/pki/CA/cacert.pem': No such file or directory
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
```

The guest is running CentOS 6.5, with Hostonly networking. I need that cos the whole setup also runs DNS and DHCP and that cannot go out of the hostonly network. However I also have a second network adapter configured, would I use that?

Comment: This error looks pretty obvious. What have you done so far to resolve it?

Comment: The error is everything but obvious, see for instance: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/Virtualization_Deployment_and_Administration_Guide/App_Hypervisor_Connection_Fail.html

Comment: Again, what have you done so far to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the wrong URI. According to the [documentation](http://libvirt.org/remote.html#Remote_URI_reference),

> Remote URIs have the general form ("[...]" meaning an optional part):
>
> ```
> driver[+transport]://[username@][hostname][:port]/[path][?extraparameters]
> ```
>
> Either the transport or the hostname must be given in order to distinguish this from a local URI.

You didn't specify the transport and the default transport is **tls**. The documentation regarding [transports](http://libvirt.org/remote.html#Remote_transports) also says this about **tls**:

> TLS 1.0 (SSL 3.1) authenticated and encrypted TCP/IP socket, usually listening on a public port number. To use this *you will need to [generate client and server certificates](http://libvirt.org/remote.html#Remote_certificates)*. The standard port is 16514.

I don't think you've generated the required certificates, therefore you're getting that error. So either generate the certificates or use another transport, for example **tcp** (unencrypted, good only for trusted networks) or **ssh** (e.g. `vbox+ssh://root@192.168.56.1/session`).

Comment: Let me try this tomorrow. I didn't generate the ssl certificates indeed.